# Setting an Iframe to always be full page on Wordpress page builder

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, wysiwyg

I am trying to set an Iframe to always be full page on Wordpress. I am using a WYSIWYG box to enter the code. The Iframe needs to be full page, as it is rendering too small. I tried to just change the size, but that un-centers it. Is there anyway I can use Custom CSS to open the Iframe link as full page, without the user having to click a full screen button.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the head of the page in the iframe:

```html
<base target="_parent">
```

This will load all links on the page in the parent window. If you want your links to load in a new window, use:

```html
<base target="_blank">
```

Hope... It's Works!!